# Autostart with AutostartCondition

Tags: xdg

I want to run some program at the certain condition.

So I have created .desktop file and put it int /etc/xdg/autostart.

Here desktop file is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=System Tray
Exec=/opt/testApp
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
NoDisplay=true
AutostartCondition=GSettings com.test testVal
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
```

And I have made a custom key with gsettings for a condition and compiled the schemas.

I confirm if the schema works, it works.

```
$> gsettings set com.test testVal true
$> gsettings get com.test testVal
```

I typed the command above, and got "true".

However the Application I registered as Autostart doesn't run.

Do I have to restart or logoff for a test?

Is there a way to test autostart without reboot or logoff?

Comment: What's the content of `/opt/testApp`?

Comment: It's a GUI application using Qt.

Comment: I use KDE, so I'm sure I'm missing some fine points here, but: If it's a gui program, it needs the desktop environment to be already running. So why not just write an autostart script for it that your desktop will run when it starts. That script can test for any conditions you like and decide what to do. For example, see http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-desktop-auto-start-or-launch-programs.html . I don't get the gsettings part, but that may just be because I don't use that desktop.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655066/autostart-with-autostartcondition and https://askubuntu.com/questions/566838/autostart-with-autostartcondition